# Delete hidden books from iTunes

Tags: itunes, windows

I'm cleaning up my iTunes library. I'm a programmer so, with the help of some nifty scripting, I'm using `iTunes Music Library.xml` to give me improved insight into my iTunes library.

In the process, I've discovered there are several books lingering in my library which I can't see in the iTunes application. I've also found the book files sitting in `iTunes Media`.

I can't for the life of me figure out how to delete these books from my library, considering I can't find them in the application. Any ideas?

**Note:** I'm running iTunes 12.3.2.35 on Windows 10. My library was moved from an old Mac (packed away but can dig it out if software version numbers available if required).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SELF ANSWER:**

On Windows, books *should* have been available from the iTunes application but, for whatever reason, they weren't for me. So, I ended up moving my iTunes library back to a Mac running OS X 10.11.

On OS X, it appears that all books functionality has been moved from iTunes to the iBooks application. I opened iBooks and it immediately offered to move books from iTunes. I then deleted the books from iBooks. After closing both iTunes and iBooks, an inspection of `iTunes Music Library.xml` shows that all the books "tracks" have been removed from my iTunes library.